# Scheduling a docker Container with a docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cron, scheduling

I have a docker container which is brought up with the help of a `docker-compose` file along with a database container. I want to do this:

- Keep the database container running
- Schedule the container with my python program to run daily, generate results and stop again

This is my configuration file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
   database:
      container_name: sql_database
      image: mysql:latest
      command: --init-file /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      ports:
       - 13306:3306
      environment:
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      volumes:
       - ./backup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

   python-container:
      container_name: python-container
      build: ./python_project
      command: python main.py
      depends_on: 
       - database
      volumes: 
       - myvol:/python_project/data

volumes: 
   myvol:
```

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Compose on its own doesn't have a job scheduler; it's common both to run a dedicated cron container and to use your host's cron to launch the task for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to ask the same thing. Seems silly to keep a container going 24/7 just to run one job a day (in my case, `certbot renew`).

I think there may be a way to fake this using the `RESTART_POLICY` option with a long delay and no maximum retries, but I haven't tried it yet.

**EDIT:** Apparently `restart_policy` only works for swarms. Pity.

Answer (score 0):

If the underlying container has a bash shell, you set the `command` to run a loop with a delay, like this:

`while true; do python main.py; sleep 1; done`